# Is there a plugin to display which templates and template parts are being called by WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

The title may make you feel weird. What my meaning is that I know in Magento, there is a plugin, I can type "?tp=1&code=magento", press return, the page will be like this: www.sephenry.net/temp.jpg (I don't have enough reputation to post images)

So that I can find the file of different modules and modify them. I am new to wordpress, and I hope I make myself clearly and hope someone can give a hand. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to see what *templates* and *template parts* are being loaded: try the [What The File plugin.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/what-the-file/)

Comment: Is there any other plugins so that I can check every part on the page?